# How to bind the values we get in json object d to a gridview?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json, c#-4.0

I am getting the values in json object d as follows:

```
carlos 21 Melinda 37 Andrew 41
```

Now how can I bind these values to asp.net gridview?

**aspx:**

```
function get(strcode) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Default.aspx/MyMethod",
        data: "{'Code':'" + strcode + "'}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
            // Here I want to bind the gridview to the values contained in d
            //also the values in d are dynamic means i am getting them from the datatable
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: GridView is server-side control, and your json result is client-side. Why would you want to do that?

Comment: as @abhitalks say, you must use client side grid like jquery datatable at http://datatables.net/ or jqgrid at http://www.trirand.com/‎, and others jquery plugins

Answer (score 0):

GridView is rendered as html. If you know the rendering html then you can do it. GridView is rendered as html Table.

If using jQuery

```
   success: function(result) {
       var ResultData=result.d;// asssuming ResultData would be an array. (ie pass a list from your webmethod)
       $("table tr").remove();// Removing all tr. so that table (ie grid) will be empty
       var strHtml="";
       for(var i=0;i<ResultData.length;i++)
        {
          strHtml+="<tr><td>"+ResultData[i].column1+"</td><td>"+ResultData[i].column2+"</td></tr>";// Appending each tr string. column1 and column2 are properties you passed from server side
        }
       $("table").append(strHtml);// Appending the html to the table.

       }
```

Comment: I dont know much about jquery. how to use it? thanks.

Comment: Without knowing client side scripting you can't do it properly. W3Schools is always a better place to start

Comment: using webMethod ajax call you can make the relevant data available for javascript. But you must know how to use it in javaScript